# Rewrite root url call to subfolder

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I have my single page app index.html located in a sub folder. I would like people to see it when they acess the root url. What's missing in this rewrite rule?

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="SPA rewrite">
      <match url="http://app.local" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://app.local/SPA/dist" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Do you have other contents or resources in the same application.Could you please add what other contents are present ? for e.g do you have some dynamic content api/product/something etc also served from the application or it is just static website? Bceause based on the condition we can have the rule made without affecting any other contents (both dynamic and static) in the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule should be something like this:

```
<rule name="SPA rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="app.local" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/SPA/dist" />
</rule>
```

In your answer, you used incorrect patter in `<match url=` section. And for SPA you do not need to rewrite files and directories